# Container nginx with PHP-FPM dont executing PHP files

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx

i'm trying run Nginx with PHP-FPM following the tutorial (http://geekyplatypus.com/dockerise-your-php-application-with-nginx-and-php7-fpm/)
but my nginx running in docker dont interpret PHP files and return "403" error.

My "site.conf"

```
server {
index index.php index.html;
server_name learn-wordpress.com;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

}

My "docker-compose.yml"

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    container_name: 'wp'
    volumes:
      - "./:/usr/share/nginx/html"
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
  php:
    image: 'php:7.4-fpm'
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html"
```

My PHP application is Wordpress without any change.

Comment: Your PHP container in `docker-compose.yml` seems to be mounting your files to `/var/www/html`, but your Nginx configuration file has the root of `/usr/share/nginx/html`. Try and update the Nginx configuration to use `root /var/www/html;`, and update your volumes mount on your `web` (nginx) container to use the same volume mount directory.

Comment: @Reece, i tryid change the root /usr/share/nginx/html; to root /var/www/html; But not solved, now the nginx display's the default nginx "index.html"